# Redraw vue component on fetch update

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When on button click I want to refresh list of items.
Button is trigger on a sibling component.
Watch method only gets called once. But I need a constant refresh

Parent element.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Filter @changedKeywords="reloadItems"></Filter>
    <List :platforms="platforms" :filters="keywords"></List>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
imports...

export default {
  name: "Holder",
  components: {Filter, List},
  methods: {
    reloadItems: function (data){
      if(data.keywords) {this.keywords = data.keywords};
    }
  },
  data(){
    return {
      keywords : null,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to redraw child this element multiple times, on each (filter)button click

```
<template>
  <section class="list">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="holder">
        <Game v-for="data in list" :key="data.id" :data="data" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import Game from "./Game";
export default {
  name: "List",
  props: ['filters', 'platforms'],
  components: {Game},
  data() {
    return{
      list: [],
    }
  },
  watch: {
    filters: async function() {
      console.log('gets called only once!!!'); // this is where I want to fetch new items
      const res = await fetch('/api/game/list/9', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({'filters' : this.filters})
      });
      this.list = await res.json();
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps try defining `keywords` in the data of your "holder" component, like `platforms` is?

Comment: sorry I was cleaning up the code and deleted the wrong variable, it is defined. So you think watch method should be called more than once, and my code is okay-ish?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hqnspr?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHolder.vue).

Answer (score 1):

When you're watching objects and arrays you need to use a deep watcher.

#### The Solution

```
watch: {
  filter: {
    deep: true,
    async handler(next, previous) {
      //your code here
    }
  }
}
```

#### The Reason

Javascript primitives are stored by value, but Objects (including Arrays which are a special kind of Object) are stored by reference. Changing the contents of an Object doesn't change the reference, and the reference is what is being watched. Going from `null` to some object reference is an observable change, but subsequent changes aren't. When you use a deep watcher it will detect nested changes.